# ionic modal opening the previous modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ionic-framework, ionic2

Hello guys I am trying to open a modal. the thing is I have binded my modal with a template poreviously now I'm trying to bind the another modal with $ionicmodal but it opening the previous one. Can somebody tell me what is it that I'm doing wrong

**First the modal is being binded in APPCtrl**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout) {

  // With the new view caching in Ionic, Controllers are only called
  // when they are recreated or on app start, instead of every page change.
  // To listen for when this page is active (for example, to refresh data),
  // listen for the $ionicView.enter event:
  //$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(e) {
  //});

  // Form data for the login modal
  $scope.action = {
    // name:'',
    // date: '',
    // type:''
  };

  $scope.placeholder="01/01/2016";

  // Create the login modal that we will use later
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/addAction.html', {
    scope: $scope
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });

  // Triggered in the login modal to close it
  $scope.closeActionModal = function() {
    console.log('hello');
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };

  // Open the login modal
  $scope.openAddActionModel = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
    $('#action_datePicker').val(new Date());
  };

  // $scope.abc = function(){
  //   console.log('asdavshahs');
  //   alert('Hello');
  // }


  // Perform the login action when the user submits the login form
  $scope.saveData = function() {
    console.log('Doing login', $scope.action);

    // Simulate a login delay. Remove this and replace with your login
    // code if using a login system
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.closeActionModal();
    }, 1000);
  };
})
```

**Now I'm tring to bind the modal over here in show List user but it is showing the previous one**

```
.controller('optionActionCtrl' , function($scope, $timeout , $http , $ionicModal){



  $scope.closeActionModal = function() {
    console.log('hello');
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };

  // Open the login modal
  $scope.openAddActionModel = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
    // $('#action_datePicker').val(new Date());
  };

  $scope.showListOfUser = function(){
    //call made to the server
    //bind the modal to get it open
     $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/showUsers.html', {
      scope: $scope
    }).then(function(modal) {
      debugger;
      $scope.modal = modal;
    });
    $scope.modal.show();
    // add all the users 
    $scope.users = ['a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd'];
  };
})
```

Please tell me what is it that I'm doing wrong

**UPDATE**

Now I'm trying to open a state and see some data bbut the problem is I'm not able to see the users rather then all the HTML is being rendered. Here is the code for my view:

```
<ion-view view-title="ShowUserList">
  <ion-content>
    <!-- <ion-checkbox ng-model='checkStatus1' ng-click="showAlert(checkStatus1)">
        <h2 class="ng-binding">{{tittle}}</h2>
        <span class="distance ng-binding"></span>
        <h3 class="ng-binding">Created : {{created}}</h3>
        <h3 class="ng-binding">Target : {{targetD}}</h3>
    </ion-checkbox>  -->

    <ion-list>
      <ion-item  collection-repeat="user in users">
        Hello, {{user}}!
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>


  </ion-content>
```

and I've changed the controller a little bit

```
.controller('optionActionCtrl' , function($scope, $timeout , $http , $ionicModal , $state){
    // Triggered in the login modal to close it

    $scope.users = [];

  $scope.closeActionModal = function() {
    console.log('hello');
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };

  // Open the login modal
  $scope.openAddActionModel = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
    // $('#action_datePicker').val(new Date());
  };

  $scope.showListOfUser = function(){
    debugger;
    // add all the users 
    $scope.users = ['a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd'];

    $state.go('app.UserListForAssigned')
  };
})
```

Comment: `$scope.modal.show()` is called before the new modal is actually created. Put `$scope.modal.show()` inside the callback of `fromTemplateUrl` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your `optionActionCtrl` controller. Put `$scope.modal.show()` inside the callback.

```
.controller('optionActionCtrl' , function($scope, $timeout , $http , $ionicModal){
    $scope.closeActionModal = function() {
        console.log('hello');
        $scope.modal.hide();
    };

    $scope.openAddActionModel = function() {
        $scope.modal.show();
    };

    $scope.showListOfUser = function () {
        $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/showUsers.html', {
            scope: $scope
        }).then(function(modal) {
            $scope.modal = modal;
            $scope.modal.show(); // Moved inside the callback
            $scope.users = ['a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd']; // I assume this is relevant to your modal
        });
    };
})
```

Comment: Thanks it helped. I would like to know another thing. that is rather than showing a modal I would like to go to render another view on when coming into this modal. The problem that I'm facing is I cannot see the data over ther which I'm sending in `$scope.users`

Comment: @J.Doe Up vote and accept this answer, then post another one and I'll help you there. I believe these are two separate questions.

Comment: @J.Doe And also post the contents of `templates/showUsers.html`.

Comment: I'm facing a problem I can post once in 90 minutes

Comment: Interesting. :) Alright then just edit your current question and put contents of `templates/showUsers.html` in there.

Comment: @J.Doe I'm will try to replicate your problem and post back my results.

Comment: I'm tried replicating your issue but I can't. Here is a fiddle that works just fine. https://jsfiddle.net/eriktodx/09kcez31/ I hope it helps in some way.

Comment: right now I'm not trying to open the modal but I'm trying to to another view but the problem is I get to another view the but data is not showns